# How to write typeof in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'd like to ask you how can I rewrite this piece of objective-c code to swift:

```
__weak typeof(self) this = self;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Capture list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) in your closure. You can choose between using [weak self] or [unowned self]. The difference is that in unowned self you must be 100% sure the object is never nil. Example:

```
var myClosure = {
    [unowned self] in
    print(self.description)
}
```